# How to know executor IPs for a Spark application?

Tags: apache-spark

I want to get all the IPs of executors at runtime, which API in Spark should I use? Or any other method to get IPs at runtime?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a class in Apache Spark namely ExecutorInfo which has a method executorHost() which returns the Executor Host IP.

Answer (score 2):

You should use [SparkListener](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.scheduler.SparkListener) abstract class and intercept  two executor-specific events - `SparkListenerExecutorAdded` and `SparkListenerExecutorRemoved`.

```scala
override def onExecutorAdded(executorAdded: SparkListenerExecutorAdded): Unit = {
  val execId = executorAdded.executorId
  val host = executorAdded.executorInfo.executorHost
  executors += (execId -> host)
  println(s">>> executor id=$execId added on host=$host")
}

override def onExecutorRemoved(executorRemoved: SparkListenerExecutorRemoved): Unit = {
  val execId = executorRemoved.executorId
  val host = executors remove execId getOrElse "Host unknown"
  println(s">>> executor id=$execId removed from host=$host")
}
```

The entire working project is in my [Spark Executor Monitor Project](https://github.com/jaceklaskowski/spark-workshop/tree/gh-pages/solutions/spark-listener-executor-monitor).

Comment: I also tried this option, though I need to provide this list of executors to do some transformation of the RDD, like mapping partition to the executor ( sticky partition). But looks like this will be called not when the sc.start() is being called, but it might be latter on as well. so, not able to get the list before calling some functions on the dstream to transform RDD.   thanks for your time !

Comment: If you need to request particular executors *before* an action (not to know the executors assigned to your application) you'd have to develop a custom RDD that would have the list as `preferredLocation`. That would require developing your own custom `DStream` which is doable. What are you really trying to achieve? What's the use case?